# Android addmob app force closed

Tags: android, webview, admob

I am working with android app, and I am trying to add the google addmob to my app. And there are no errors in my code but the app seems to be force closed while running. I cant find the error. Please help me,
 I used the code -

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "my add id"); 
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);      
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(false);
adView.loadAd(request);
```

please help me since i am new to android development

Logcat:

```
11-09 17:26:43.508: E/AndroidRuntime(8982): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862) 
11-09 17:26:43.508: E/AndroidRuntime(8982): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView
```

Comment: no errors occured but it force closed while running :(

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
 
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>

Comment: 11-09 17:26:43.508: E/AndroidRuntime(8982):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862)
11-09 17:26:43.508: E/AndroidRuntime(8982): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView

Comment: seems like you should fix your build path

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
1. download latest google-play-services,jar
2. add jar to project build path

**main.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lnrMain">

</LinearLayout>

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LinearLayout lnrMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lnrMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrMain);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AdView adView = new AdView(MyActivity.this);
                adView.setAdUnitId("0445b7141d9d4e1b");
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
                AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
                adView.loadAd(builder.build());
                lnrMain.addView(adView);
            }
        });

    }
}

**AndroidManifest.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: adView.setAdUnitId("5655767");
  adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
  layout.addView(adView);
  AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
  builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had my first app integrated with admob and what I did is just I added a .jar Library to Java Build Path,. When in Manifest file I added these lines above closing application tag:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

and these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is how my Manifest.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="PACKAGENAME"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When in my main_acitivty.xml I added these lines of code where I actually want to see my Ad Banner:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="YOU-ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

I actually did not write any code in my .java file. Because you can choose whetever to implement AdMob via XML or programatically.

All these steps are provided in here -> [AdMob Banners](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android)

Comment: Try to go to your Project Properties, when go to "Java Build Path". In the next window go to the "Libraries" and when "Add External JARs". Finally, in the same screen go to "Order and Export" tab and check "GoogleAdMobsAdsSDK". Have you done this?

Or maybe try this solution ->> http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  here is my code am used

  ****MainActivity.java`




   package com.example.smacon;
   import com.google.ads.*;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Surface;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;


   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private AdView adView;
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        //test mode on EMULATOR
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

        //test mode on DEVICE (this example code must be replaced with your device uniquq ID)
        adRequest.addTestDevice("4G74FC73D62D42B62A7F7DA61EF5F776");

        adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);      

        // Initiate a request to load an ad in test mode.
        // You can keep this even when you release your app on the market, because
        // only emulators and your test device will get test ads. The user will receive real ads.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("my url");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); 


}


    @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
   if (adView != null) {
   adView.destroy();
   }
   super.onDestroy();
   }

   }

   ***** MyWebViewClient.java



     package com.example.smacon;

     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.webkit.WebView;
     import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


     public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
 // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
     } 

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    // webProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

   @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
   }

   @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

   }

    **** manifest




    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smacon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smacon.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode
       |screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
    </activity>

    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>



   ****activity_main.xml



   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >


   <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="7565756565"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

  </LinearLayout>



   no errors in this code. But it is forced closed . :(
```